# Regex for get content between html tags without tags inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to get content between HTML tags, without tags inside it.

**Example**

`<p>Text content <img src=""> </p>`

I want to extract `Text content` only(without `<img>`).

I tried using this regex `/(?<=\<p[^>]*>)(.*?)(?=\<\/p\>)/g`, but this matches the content with `<img>`.

How can i solve this ?

Thank you

**Edit**

What I'm trying to do is replace the content inside tags with unicode characters.

Comment: Parsing HTML with RegEx is ***always*** the wrong choice.  Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: You are lucky your question did not get down voted into oblivion. Normally thats what happends when you ask a question about regex and HTML in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Regex, make use of DOM parser and create a dummy element first

```
var str = `<p>Text content <img src=""> </p>`; 
var el = document.createElement( "div" ); //create dummy element
el.innerHTML = str; //assign str as innerHTML
var output = el.querySelector( "p" ).textContent; //get the textcontent inside p
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = `<p>Text content <img src=""> </p>`;
var el = document.createElement("div"); //create dummy element
el.innerHTML = str; //assign str as innerHTML
var output = el.querySelector("p").textContent; //get the textcontent inside p
console.log(output);
```

For replacing this content with another string, change the node value of the text node

```
Array.from(el.querySelector("p").childNodes)
  .forEach(s => 
    s.nodeType == 3 && s.nodeValue.trim().length > 0 ? s.nodeValue = strToReplaceWith : "");
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = `<p>Text content <img src=""> </p>`;
var strToReplaceWith = "abc";
var el = document.createElement("div"); //create dummy element
el.innerHTML = str; //assign str as innerHTML
Array.from(el.querySelector("p").childNodes)
  .forEach(s => 
    s.nodeType == 3 && s.nodeValue.trim().length > 0 ? s.nodeValue = strToReplaceWith : "");
console.log(el.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but I'm trying to do is replace the content inside tags with Unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on a same approach. But you code replaces one `p` elements content only. Check it

Comment: This answer is doing exactly what your question had asked for in the example. For doing multiple such replaces, you can use `querySelectorAll`. As far as I am concerned, I have already answered your question.